# Vim Tagbar is empty after installing CoffeeTags

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'm having the hardest time getting [CoffeeTags](https://github.com/lukaszkorecki/CoffeeTags) to run in Vim.

As the website suggests, I've installed the `CoffeeTags` gem and appended the configuration to my `~/.vimrc`. When I open Tagbar it's empty.

Here's a screenshot summarizing the problem:

[image]

Am I missing something? I'm running Ruby 1.9.2, Vim 7.3, CoffeeScript 1.1.3, and Node.js 0.6.2. and OS X Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was Ruby. As far as I can tell, CoffeeTags doesn't work in Ruby 1.9. After switching to Ruby 1.8 CoffeeTags worked flawlessly.

I verified this on OS X 10.7.2 running rvm and Arch Linux not running rvm.

Comment: For what it's worth, CoffeeTags does work with Ruby 1.9. I just verified this myself, though that still doesn't get to the root of your problem.

Answer (score 5):

CoffeeTags seems to generate invalid tags files for me.  Whenever I tried to use tags files generated by it in vim I would get:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>19_CommandTShowTagFinder:
line    2:
E431: Format error in tags file "tags"
Before byte 156
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

In the end I'm not sure how necessary it is.  I added this:

```
--langdef=coffee
--langmap=coffee:.coffee
--regex-coffee=/(^|=[ \t])*class ([A-Za-z.]+)( extends [A-Za-z.]+)?$/\2/c,class/
--regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*(module\.)?(exports\.)?@?([A-Za-z.]+):.*[-=]>.*$/\3/f,function/
--regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*(module\.)?(exports\.)?([A-Za-z.]+)[ \t]+=.*[-=]>.*$/\3/f,function/
--regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*([A-Za-z.]+)[ \t]+=[^->\n]*$/\1/v,variable/
```

to my ~/.ctags file and then just used the regular exuberant-ctags utility:
`find . -iname '*\.coffee*' | ctags -L-`

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that your `filetype` is set incorrectly. Try `:set filetype?` in one of your coffeescript buffers. The configuration that the gem creates assumes that the filetype is set to `coffee`, so if that's not the case for you then it won't work. In that case add a line like this to your `vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.coffee setfiletype coffee
```

Maybe I should add a note about that in an empty Tagbar window...

Comment: Please do add that note: We love extra information!

Comment: Odd, still no luck. `:set filetype` definitely returns `filetype=coffee` yet the Tagbar window remains empty. I'm so stumped with this.

Comment: Hm, then I can't think of anything specific offhand. Have you tried calling coffeetags manually to see whether it actually generates tags for your file? Is it in your $PATH? Is your vimrc available somewhere?

Comment: CoffeeTags at the commandline seems to be generating tags properly and it's in my path. Here's my [.vimrc](https://gist.github.com/bf86b8bc9d24223c7656) and [.gvimrc](https://gist.github.com/31b39437d604fefdc0be).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install ruby tagbar docs suggest:
https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/wiki

```
let g:tagbar_type_coffee = {
    \ 'ctagstype' : 'coffee',
    \ 'kinds'     : [
        \ 'c:classes',
        \ 'm:methods',
        \ 'f:functions',
        \ 'v:variables',
        \ 'f:fields',
    \ ]
\ }

" Posix regular expressions for matching interesting items. Since this will 
" be passed as an environment variable, no whitespace can exist in the options
" so [:space:] is used instead of normal whitespaces.
" Adapted from: https://gist.github.com/2901844
let s:ctags_opts = '
  \ --langdef=coffee
  \ --langmap=coffee:.coffee
  \ --regex-coffee=/(^|=[ \t])*class ([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]+\.)*([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]+)( extends ([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)?$/\3/c,class/
  \ --regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*(module\.)?(exports\.)?@?(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+):.*[-=]>.*$/\3/m,method/
  \ --regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*(module\.)?(exports\.)?(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)[ \t]*=.*[-=]>.*$/\3/f,function/
  \ --regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)[ \t]*=[^->\n]*$/\1/v,variable/
  \ --regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)[ \t]*=[^->\n]*$/\1/f,field/
  \ --regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+):[^->\n]*$/\1/f,static field/
  \ --regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+):[^->\n]*$/\1/f,field/
  \ --regex-coffee=/((constructor|initialize):[ \t]*\()@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?/\3/f,field/
  \ --regex-coffee=/((constructor|initialize):[ \t]*\()@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?(,[ \t]*@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?){0}/\8/f,field/
  \ --regex-coffee=/((constructor|initialize):[ \t]*\()@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?(,[ \t]*@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?){1}/\8/f,field/
  \ --regex-coffee=/((constructor|initialize):[ \t]*\()@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?(,[ \t]*@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?){2}/\8/f,field/
  \ --regex-coffee=/((constructor|initialize):[ \t]*\()@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?(,[ \t]*@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?){3}/\8/f,field/
  \ --regex-coffee=/((constructor|initialize):[ \t]*\()@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?(,[ \t]*@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?){4}/\8/f,field/
  \ --regex-coffee=/((constructor|initialize):[ \t]*\()@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?(,[ \t]*@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?){5}/\8/f,field/
  \ --regex-coffee=/((constructor|initialize):[ \t]*\()@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?(,[ \t]*@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?){6}/\8/f,field/
  \ --regex-coffee=/((constructor|initialize):[ \t]*\()@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?(,[ \t]*@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?){7}/\8/f,field/
  \ --regex-coffee=/((constructor|initialize):[ \t]*\()@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?(,[ \t]*@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?){8}/\8/f,field/
  \ --regex-coffee=/((constructor|initialize):[ \t]*\()@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?(,[ \t]*@(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*)+)([ \t]*=[ \t]*[^,)]+)?){9}/\8/f,field/'

let $CTAGS = substitute(s:ctags_opts, '\v\\([nst]\)', '\\\\\1', 'g')
```